# Pyspark program failed to run in OOZIE due to import error

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, pyspark

I am trying to run a simple PySpark program in Oozie and I am failing to run it successfully. I have a simple PySpark program which loads a file on HDFS in RDD. I convert that RDD to a DATAFRAME and then convert it PANDAS. I am getting an error for importing PANDAS.
I have anaconda python distribution installed on my Cloudera VM version 5.4.2. I have the Anaconda dir (`/home/cloudera/anaconda/bin/`) added to my systems `CLASSPATH`. the following is the output of `echo $PATH` statement:

> /home/cloudera/anaconda/bin:/home/cloudera/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/firefox:/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/cloudera/bin

The program runs fine via CLI but it is failing when I try to run it via OOZIE job.

The following is the error log I get:

> Stdoutput /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py:156: UserWarning:   Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated,please use pyspark.sql.Row instead
>   Stdoutput   warnings.warn("Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated,"
>   Stdoutput Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Stdoutput   File "/home/cloudera/Dataframe/apps/shell/lib/test.py", line 48, in 
>   Stdoutput     cleand = inputRDD.toPandas()
>   Stdoutput   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 717, in toPandas
>   Stdoutput     import pandas as pd
>   Stdoutput ImportError: No module named pandas
>   Exit code of the Shell command 1
>   <<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<
>   <<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
>   Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class   [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
>   Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
>   Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file:   hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000000-150724190306010-oozie-oozi-W/shell-node--shell/action-data.seq
>   Oozie Launcher ends

Can anyone please help me how I can run the program successfully?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable?

Comment: No I have not tried setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable. If you can help me to set that variable that would be of great help.

Comment: It should be set in `conf/spark-env.sh` and point to the Python executable. There should be a template file in `conf/spark-env.sh.template`.

Comment: Thank You so much. That really worked :)... Thanks alit @zero323

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it as an answer then.

Comment: @zero323 Where is the conf/spark-env.sh? I tried to os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/s/anaconda/users/xxxxx/miniconda2/bin/python" in my Python script. But still got the import pandas error.